# Fast fuzzy/approximate search in dictionary of strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby, performance, algorithm, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search

I have a dictionary of 50K to 100K strings (can be up to 50+ characters) and I am trying to find whether a given string is in the dictionary with some "edit" distance tolerance. (Levenshtein for example). I am fine pre-computing any type of data structure before doing the search.

**My goal to run thousands of strings against that dictionary as fast as possible and returns the closest neighbor. I would be fine just getting a boolean that say whether a given is in the dictionary or not if there was a significantly faster algorithm to do so**

For this, I first tried to compute all the Levenshtein distances and take the minimum and it was obviously horribly slow. So I tried to implement a Levenshtein Trie based on this article http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=114

See my gist here for reproducing the benchmark: https://gist.github.com/nicolasmeunier/7493947

Here are a few benchmarks I got on my machine:

**Edit distance of 0 (perfect match)**

```
Benchmark.measure { 10.times { dictionary.search(random_word, 0) } }
<Benchmark::Tms:0x007fa59bad8908 @label="", @real=0.010889, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.00999999999999801, @total=0.00999999999999801>
```

**Edit distance of 2, it becomes a LOT slower **

```
Benchmark.measure { 10.times { dictionary.search(random_word, 2) } }
<Benchmark::Tms:0x007fa58c9ca778 @label="", @real=3.404604, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.020000000000000018, @utime=3.3900000000000006, @total=3.4100000000000006>
```

And it goes downhill from there and become extremely slow for edit distance larger than 2. (1+ second on average per tested string).

I would like to know how/if I could speed this up significantly. If there are existing solutions already implemented in ruby/gems, I also don't want to reinvent the wheel...

EDIT 1: In my case, I expect most of the strings I am matching against the dictionary NOT to be in there. So if there are any algorithm to quickly discard a string, that could really help.

Thanks,
Nicolas

Comment: Nicolas, I'm hesitant to comment because I'm not familiar with the literature and don't want to sidetrack the discussion, but I was reminded of a problem I had many moons ago, that of determining if a file was identical to any file in a large "library" on a remote computer. I indexed the files on a "file signature", the signature being the result of a type of CRC (cyclic redundancy check) calculation (a Fixnum, but I don't recall how many bytes).  It was very fast and 100% accurate.  The idea would be to calculate a signature for each string and then look that up in the index.

Comment: Were you looking for 100% identical files or did that allow for any margin of error? Was that something you could control? I will look into it more. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://github.com/kiyoka/fuzzy-string-match) and [this](https://github.com/seamusabshere/fuzzy_match)?

Comment: The first one only seem to compute distance between 2 words and do not implement any index/tree/ngrams data structure to optimize when searching in a dictionary. My first try with the second one are pretty slow so far...

Comment: Nicolas, in practice it was 100%.  To use a signature to discriminate between two files of equal length, with certainty, the signature must be at least as long as the files, so nothing is gained.  However, the signature doesn't have to be very long before the number of possible signatures vastly exceeds the number of files on all the computers in the world. I made the signature long enough that the probability that two unequal files would have the same signature was far too small to worry about.  It was never a problem.

Comment: Got it. Something like LSH: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing. But I don't think that's what I am looking for here unfortunately

Comment: can you show your dictionary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a pair of gems, [fuzzily](https://github.com/mezis/fuzzily) and [blurrily](https://github.com/mezis/blurrily) which do trigrams-based fuzzy matching.
Given your (low) volume of data Fuzzily will be easier to integrate and about as fast, in with either you'd get answers within 5-10ms on modern hardware.

Given both are trigrams-based (which is indexable), not edit-distance-based (which isn't), you'd probably have to do this in two passes:

- first ask either gem for a set of best matches trigrams-wise
- then compare results with your input string, using Levenstein
- and return the min for that measure.

In Ruby (as you asked), using Fuzzily + the [Text gem](https://github.com/threedaymonk/text), obtaining the records withing the edit distance threshold would look like:

```
MyRecords.find_by_fuzzy_name(input_string).select { |result|
  Text::Levenshtein.distance(input_string, result.name)] < my_distance_threshold
}
```

This performas a handful of well optimized database queries and a few

Caveats:

- if the "minimal" edit distance you're looking for is high, you'll still be doing lots of Levenshteins.
- using trigrams assumes your input text is latin text or close to (european languages basically).
- there probably are edge cases since nothing garantees that "number of matching trigrams" is a great general approximation to "edit distance".

Comment: I'm currently doing exactly that with Blurrily so I have in memory indexes and using the levenshtein-ffi gem (C implementation - 4x faster that my own Ruby implementation) and I get request in the matter of 1-2ms on my data, where I was in the 50 - 200ms with my pure Ruby implementation. I am totally fine with the caveats so this is the perfect solution for me. Thanks a lot for those amazing gems!

Comment: You're very welcome Nicolas. Do open Github issues if you spot any bugs, I do my best to keep them maintained!

Answer (score 5):

Approx 15 years ago I wrote fuzzy search, which can found N closes neighbors.
This is my modification of Wilbur's trigram algorithm, and this modification named "Wilbur-Khovayko algorithm".

Basic idea: To split strings by trigrams, and search maximal intersection scores.

For example, lets we have string "hello world".
This string is generates trigrams: hel ell llo "lo ", "o_w", eand so on;
Also, produces special prefix/suffix trigrams for each word, like $he $wo lo$ ld$.

Thereafter, for each trigram built index, in which term it is present.

So, this is list of term_ID for each trigram.

When user invoke some string - it also splits to trigrams, and program search maximal intersection score, and generates N-size list.

It works quick: I remember, on old Sun/solaris, 256MB ram, 200MHZ CPU, it search 100 closest term in dictionary 5,000,000 terms, in 0.25s

You can get my old source from:
http://olegh.ftp.sh/wilbur-khovayko.tar.gz

UPDATE:

I created new archive, where is Makefile adjusted for modern Linux/BSD make. 
You can download new version here: http://olegh.ftp.sh/wilbur-khovayko.tgz

Make some directory, and extract archive here:

```
mkdir F2
cd F2
tar xvfz wilbur-khovayko.tgz
make
```

Go to test directory, copy term list file (this is fixed name, termlist.txt), and 
make index:

```
 cd test/
 cp /tmp/test/termlist.txt ./termlist.txt
 ./crefdb.exe <termlist.txt
```

In this test, I used ~380,000 expired domain names:

```
wc -l termlist.txt
379430 termlist.txt
```

Run findtest application:

```
./findtest.exe

boking  <-- this is query -- word "booking" with misspeling


0001:Query: [boking]
  1:  287890 (  3.863739) [bokintheusa.com,2009-11-20,$69]
  2:  287906 (  3.569148) [bookingseu.com,2009-11-20,$69]
  3:  257170 (  3.565942) [bokitko.com,2009-11-18,$69]
  4:  302830 (  3.413791) [bookingcenters.com,2009-11-21,$69]
  5:  274658 (  3.408325) [bookingsadept.com,2009-11-19,$69]
  6:  100438 (  3.379371) [bookingresorts.com,2009-11-09,$69]
  7:  203401 (  3.363858) [bookinginternet.com,2009-11-15,$69]
  8:  221222 (  3.361689) [bobokiosk.com,2009-11-16,$69]
  . . . . 
 97:   29035 (  2.169753) [buccupbooking.com,2009-11-05,$69]
 98:  185692 (  2.169047) [box-hosting.net,2009-11-14,$69]
 99:  345394 (  2.168371) [birminghamcookinglessons.com,2009-11-25,$69]
100:  150134 (  2.167372) [bowlingbrain.com,2009-11-12,$69]
```

Comment: Very interesting! Why don't you put it on public source code platform like f.e. GitHub, Gitorious, or Bitbucket?

Comment: It had been written ~15 years ago, when github, etc was not exist. I deposited it on my own site. If you wish, you can get the source, and turn it into public open source project.

Comment: Interesting. Could you explain how I could run your code on some examples (for someone who doesn't remember much about C... :)) Thanks!

Comment: Nicolas, see UPDATE in my answer; I hope, it would be useful.

Comment: Hello! I don't see a termlist.txt in your source. What format is it expected to have?

Comment: Just text file, one term per line. You can copy your file to termlist.txt; also, program crefdb.exe uses two inputs - termlist.txt, and into stdin, it receives list of users requests for previous day (or week). From stdin, it counts trigram static, and optimize disk usage for quick retrieve most popular trigrams.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's a pretty neat piece of code you have there.

Answer (score 3):

If you are prepared to get involved with Machine Learning approaches, then this paper by Geoff Hinton will be a good starting point

http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/sh.pdf

These kind of approaches are used in places like Google etc.

Essentially you cluster your dictionary strings based on similarity. When the query string comes, instead of calculating the edit distance against the entire data set, you just compare the cluster thus reducing query time significantly.

P.S I did a bit of googling, found a Ruby implementation of another similar approach called [Locality Sensitive Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) here https://github.com/bbcrd/ruby-lsh

Answer (score 2):

Here is raw Trie-like implementation. It is totally not optimized, just a proof of concept. Pure Ruby implementation.

To test it I took 100_000 words from here http://www.infochimps.com/datasets/word-list-100000-official-crossword-words-excel-readable/downloads/195488

here is a gist for it
https://gist.github.com/fl00r/7542994

```
class TrieDict
  attr_reader :dict

  def initialize
    @dict = {}
  end

  def put(str)
    d = nil
    str.chars.each do |c|
      d && (d = (d[1][c] ||= [nil, {}])) || d = (@dict[c] ||= [nil, {}])
    end
    d[0] = true
  end

  def fetch(prefix, fuzzy = 0)
    storage = []
    str = ""
    error = 0
    recur_fetch(prefix, fuzzy, @dict, storage, str, error)
    storage
  end

  def recur_fetch(prefix, fuzzy, dict, storage, str, error)
    dict.each do |k, vals|
      e = error
      if prefix[0] != k
        e += 1
        next  if e > fuzzy
      end
      s = str + k
      storage << s  if vals[0] && (prefix.size - 1) <= (fuzzy - e)
      recur_fetch(prefix[1..-1] || "", fuzzy, vals[1], storage, s, e)
    end
  end
end

def bench
  t = Time.now.to_f
  res = nil
  10.times{ res = yield }
  e = Time.now.to_f - t
  puts "Elapsed for 10 times: #{e}"
  puts "Result: #{res}"
end

trie = TrieDict.new
File.read("/home/petr/code/tmp/words.txt").each_line do |word|
  trie.put(word.strip)
end; :ok
# Elapsed for 10 times: 0.0006465911865234375
# Result: ["hello"]
bench{ trie.fetch "hello", 1 }
# Elapsed for 10 times: 0.013643741607666016
# Result: ["cello", "hallo", "helio", "hell", "hello", "hellos", "hells", "hillo", "hollo", "hullo"]
bench{ trie.fetch "hello", 2 }
# Elapsed for 10 times: 0.08267641067504883
# Result: ["bell", "belle", "bellow", "bells", "belly", "cell", "cella", "celli", "cello", "cellos", "cells", "dell", "dells", "delly", "fell", "fella", "felloe", "fellow", "fells", "felly", "hall", "hallo", "halloa", "halloo", "hallos", "hallot", "hallow", "halls", "heal", "heals", "heel", "heels", "heil", "heils", "held", "helio", "helios", "helix", "hell", "helled", "heller", "hello", "helloed", "helloes", "hellos", "hells", "helm", "helms", "helot", "help", "helps", "helve", "herl", "herls", "hill", "hillo", "hilloa", "hillos", "hills", "hilly", "holla", "hollo", "holloa", "holloo", "hollos", "hollow", "holly", "hull", "hullo", "hulloa", "hullos", "hulls", "jell", "jells", "jelly", "mell", "mellow", "mells", "sell", "selle", "sells", "tell", "tells", "telly", "well", "wells", "yell", "yellow", "yells"]
bench{ trie.fetch "engineer", 2 }
# Elapsed for 10 times: 0.04654884338378906
# Result: ["engender", "engine", "engined", "engineer", "engineered", "engineers", "enginery", "engines"]
bench{ trie.fetch "engeneer", 1 }
# Elapsed for 10 times: 0.005484580993652344
# Result: ["engender", "engineer"]
```

Comment: Interesting! Faster than my implementation. Would you mind explaining a bit your underlying data structure, especially what this crazy put method does?

Comment: Underlying data structure is a kind of a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). Put method is putting chars into nodes of their parents. And first item of node array (bool) is a flag that this is complete word (from top to this node)

Comment: It could be rewritten as a gem with C extension for better performance (2-5x boost I believe)

Comment: Note for people reading this: The accuracy of this algorithm is not very good. If you tried: trie.fetch ("ello", 1), it would not return "hello" because it doesn't take into account insert and delete cost, only replace. It is fast but not very usable in case you're looking for similar words where real-life typos can be made.