# Performance issues during fuzzy comparison for large lists

Tags: python, fuzzy-comparison

There are two lists - each containing names.
Each name in list1 is to be compared against names in list2 to find out for exact/similar names.

I am no expert at the fuzzy comparison. Decided to use fuzzywuzzy for this problem.

Sample code:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, process
import datetime
file1 = open('list1.txt', 'r');names = file1.readlines();file1.close;
file2 = open('list2.txt', 'r');choices = file2.readlines();file2.close;
for name in names:
    print ("--");
    print(datetime.datetime.now());
    length =  len(process.extractBests(
        name, 
        choices, 
        scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio, 
        score_cutoff=85
    ));    
    print (name.strip() + ":" + str(length));
    print(datetime.datetime.now());
```

Sample output:

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fuzzywuzzy\fuzz.py:35: UserWarning: Using slow pure-python SequenceMatcher. Install python-Levenshtein to remove this warning
  warnings.warn('Using slow pure-python SequenceMatcher. Install python-Levenshtein to remove this warning')
--
2018-08-12 11:21:55.821950
Ara Edgecomb:5
2018-08-12 11:21:57.921380
--
2018-08-12 11:21:57.922381
Carita Burnley:5
2018-08-12 11:22:00.155454
--
```

The list2 contains only 10K names(for testing purpose). Even with such a small list, each iteration is taking more than 2 secs. In reality, list2 contains in excess of 1 million. So - definitely this is not a practical solution.

So, seeking advice if there is anything that can be improved upon.
If fuzzywuzzy is not the right tool, please provide pointers in the right direction.

*Regarding "Install python-Levenshtein"-I have tried but still not able to get the module installed. I don't anticipate a sea change in performance anyways.*

Edit#1:
As per suggestion from ForceBru, I installed python-Levenshtein. It helped and the average iteration time came down **from ~2secs to .7secs** (when comparing against 10K names). Still, it is too slow for comparing against 1M+ names. Any suggestions would be a great help!

Edit#2:
Just a passing thought -

- do we have anything like "coarse matching" to narrow down the list and then do "fine matching" to get the exact similarity index?

Comment: In many CPU-intensive tasks C code runs much, much faster than plain Python code, so you really should try to install this C module first. You'll need a C (or C++) compiler to do this.

Comment: @ForceBru Thanks for the suggestion. I have now installed the module and updated the question with findings.

Comment: I don't know of another package, but you can safely dismiss fuzzywuzzy as a choice for your task. It is meant for small sets where the 'choices' might be variable and uses a full search through the set of choices. What you need is a solution that works with a large but non-changing set of choices - these use indexes rather than searching through the entire set and are much faster. This answer might be helpful as as starting point, though it isn't in Python:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20012873/fast-fuzzy-approximate-search-in-dictionary-of-strings-in-ruby

Comment: what stops you from following the warning and installing **python-levenshtein** for faster comparison?

Comment: @lenik I have indeed installed python-levenshtein and posted my findings under Edit#1 in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Divide and concur. First you need to find out how big of a background list you can actually use, so I would suggest running one name against the full mill+ list, just to know how long it takes.

Next break list 1 into a bunch of bite sized pieces. Depending on how long it takes you might chose something like 10 or 50 names per chunk. So now you have a list of file ones each member of which will be fuzzy comped against your big file 2.

The next step is to add a sys argument to your analysis script so that you can specify which chunk to run on, ensure that the output file name includes the chunk info (input file name) and write a controller script that will kick off the analysis for each chuck as it's own python process.

Finally you can amalgamate all of your chunk results into a final singular results file. Odds are good that your compy still won't have the juice to chew threw the whole problem but at least this approach will allow you to leverage the width of your processor.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [SOUNDEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) algorithm that bins together similarly sounding English words. Used when the telephone sound quality was not as good as today. Probably still used somewhere today.

Comment: I have actually gone through Soundex algorithm and ended up using double-metaphone(as it is the more recent version of phonetic algorithms). But I, honestly, couldn't get them to fit my purpose. For instance "Soumya Ranjan Das" and "Das Soumya Ranjan" generates completely separate metaphones.I can't use these metaphones to compare unless I create all possible word combinations and then generate metaphones for each of them - which sounds horribly wrong.I understand me being naive in asking this, but can you please briefly explain how to utilize them in this scenario? Thanks.

Comment: @Soumya from "Soumya Ranjan Das" you're supposed to get 3 different codes (1 code for every word). Before storing them somewhere, sort them alphabetically. Then when you encounter the same words in a different order, the sorting will take care of the wrong order, and SOUNDEX will take care about difference in word spelling.